# XSLT validation working for the first for-each then failing

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT to validate a document and it's not working the way I anticipated.

I have an XML document in which each `LodgementInstructions` or `LodgementDocument` has a pair of `Counterparts`, and each of these has a set of `InvolvedParties`. I want to make sure that each 'Counterpart' has the same set of `InvolvedParties` based on the `PartyId`, so this is my plan: for each `LodgementDocument` or `LodgementInstructions`, get a set of all `InvolvedParties` across all `Counterparts`, `$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds`. Then, for each `Counterpart` compare `$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds` with the set of `PartyId`s for just that counterpart, `$partyIdsForThisCounterpart`. If they are the same, all is good; if they are different then I build an error message.

But, the behaviour I'm seeing is that the first counterpart passes the difference test, but second fails, even though the nodesets *look* the same to me. This is my debug output:

```
<SemanticErrors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    document IDs
    LI1402992691249

        Counterpart ID [CP1402992691548]
        setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds = [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>]            
        partyIdsForThisCounterpart = [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>]                        
        Are [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>] and [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>] the same? [true]

        Counterpart ID [CP1402992694237]
        setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds = [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>]            
        partyIdsForThisCounterpart = [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>]                        
        Are [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>] and [<PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>] the same? [false]

            Validation error:
            Those elements that are in the first set but not the second:
            <PartyId>1</PartyId><PartyId>2</PartyId>

            ...
```

I'm using the set difference function from http://exslt.org/set/index.html, but I don't think the problem is here because I've swapped it out and used set operations from Sal Mangano's *XSLT Cookbook* (chapters 1 and 9) and got the same results.

I'm assuming my functional programming mind set is askew. I can't see why the set difference is failing on the second iteration. Can any one see what I might be doing wrong?

This is the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LodgementVerification>
    <LodgementCase>        
        <ElnLodgementCaseId>12345</ElnLodgementCaseId>
        <LodgementInstructions>
            <ElnDocumentId>LI1402992691249</ElnDocumentId>
            <Counterpart>
                <Counterpart>
                    <CounterpartData>
                        <ElnCounterpartId>CP1402992691548</ElnCounterpartId>
                        <ElnLodgementCaseId>1402986735664</ElnLodgementCaseId>
                        <ElnDocumentId>LI1402992691249</ElnDocumentId>
                        <CounterpartContent>
                            <LodgementInstructions>
                                <LodgementCaseDetail>
                                    <DocumentCount>1</DocumentCount>
                                </LodgementCaseDetail>
                            </LodgementInstructions>
                        </CounterpartContent>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>1</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>2</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                    </CounterpartData>
                </Counterpart>
            </Counterpart>
            <Counterpart>
                <Counterpart>
                    <CounterpartData>
                        <ElnCounterpartId>CP1402992694237</ElnCounterpartId>
                        <ElnLodgementCaseId>1402986735664</ElnLodgementCaseId>
                        <ElnDocumentId>LI1402992691249</ElnDocumentId>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>1</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>2</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                    </CounterpartData>
                </Counterpart>
            </Counterpart>
        </LodgementInstructions>
        <DocumentCount>1</DocumentCount>
        <LodgementDocument>
            <ElnDocumentId>M1402987029798</ElnDocumentId>
            <Counterpart>
                <Counterpart>
                    <CounterpartData>
                        <ElnCounterpartId>CP1402992691501</ElnCounterpartId>
                        <ElnDocumentId>M1402987029798</ElnDocumentId>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>1</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>2</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                    </CounterpartData>
                </Counterpart>
            </Counterpart>
            <Counterpart>
                <Counterpart>
                    <CounterpartData>
                        <ElnCounterpartId>CP1402992691500</ElnCounterpartId>
                        <ElnDocumentId>M1402987029798</ElnDocumentId>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>1</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                        <InvolvedParty>
                            <PartyId>2</PartyId>
                            <PartyType>Organisation</PartyType>
                        </InvolvedParty>
                    </CounterpartData>
                </Counterpart>
            </Counterpart>
        </LodgementDocument>
    </LodgementCase>
</LodgementVerification>
```

And, I'm using this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SemanticErrors>

            <xsl:for-each select="//LodgementInstructions | //LodgementDocument">
                <xsl:variable name="elnDocumentId" select="ElnDocumentId"/>
                <xsl:variable name="elnDocumentIDs" select="./Counterpart/Counterpart/CounterpartData/ElnDocumentId"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="CheckInvolvedParties">
                    <xsl:with-param name="elnDocumentIDs" select="$elnDocumentIDs"/>
                </xsl:call-template>                
            </xsl:for-each>

        </SemanticErrors>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Check if each counterpart for a document ID contains the same set of involved-party reference IDs -->
    <xsl:template name="CheckInvolvedParties">      
        <xsl:param name="elnDocumentIDs"/>

        document IDs
        <xsl:value-of select="$elnDocumentIDs"/>

        <!-- For each document ID... -->
        <xsl:for-each select="current()[ElnDocumentId=$elnDocumentIDs]">

            <xsl:variable name="setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds" select="set:distinct(//InvolvedParty/PartyId)" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"/>            

            <xsl:for-each select="Counterpart">
                <!-- For each document counterpart, make sure it contains just $setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds... -->                          
                <xsl:call-template name="ValidateCounterpartsPartyIds">
                    <xsl:with-param name="setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds" select="$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds"/>                  
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>           
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    <!--  --> 
    <xsl:template name="ValidateCounterpartsPartyIds">        
        <xsl:param name="setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds"/>

        <!-- Check if there are any counterparts to check. -->
        <xsl:if test="./*[text()]">                    
            Counterpart ID [<xsl:value-of select="Counterpart/CounterpartData/ElnCounterpartId"/>]
            setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds = [<xsl:copy-of select="$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds"/>]
            <xsl:variable name="partyIdsForThisCounterpart" select="Counterpart/CounterpartData/InvolvedParty/PartyId"/>
            partyIdsForThisCounterpart = [<xsl:copy-of select="Counterpart/CounterpartData/InvolvedParty/PartyId"/>]
            <xsl:variable name="setDifference" select="set:difference($setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds, $partyIdsForThisCounterpart)"  xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"/>            
            Are [<xsl:copy-of select="$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds"/>] and [<xsl:copy-of select="$partyIdsForThisCounterpart"/>] the same? [<xsl:value-of select="count($setDifference) = 0"/>]

            <xsl:if test="count($setDifference) > 0" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets">                
                Validation error:
                Those elements that are in the first set but not the second:
                <xsl:copy-of select="$setOfAllCounterpartPartyIds[count(. | $partyIdsForThisCounterpart) != count($partyIdsForThisCounterpart)]"/>                           
            </xsl:if>                      
        </xsl:if>        
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why do you want to validate the document with XSLT? It is the job of grammars such as XML Schema, Relax NG or Schematron...

Comment: @potame: I very much wish I could use something other than XSLT for this task, but I'm maintaining a legacy system and I have some fixed constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked through the logic fully, but as far as I can see you want sets of distinct PartyID *values*, whereas your code is looking for distinct PartyID *nodes*. It's possible for two distinct nodes to have the same value.

I'm afraid this kind of problem in XSLT 1.0 is quite tough. I would expect to see something along the lines of Muenchian grouping: define a key for your PartyID values, and when you encounter a particular PartyID, substitute it with the first PartyID having that particular value; once you've done this, distinct nodes will represent distinct values.